# Brainlag from Require() and file_get_contents()

Tags: php

**Hello Everyone,**
**ihave two problems**

I have problem with Header(Location)

it doesn't redirect the page it's like include()

i'm making a protection with `session` and add it to files i want to protect with session in different Paths 
 the protection code in files

```
<?php
require('../file.php');
if ($_SESSION["logged"] == false) {
header('location: ../filetwo.php');

 }
?>
```

but it doesn't redirect to filetwo.php it's open it in the same page
and this cause alot of errors

**The Second problem with `Require()`**

when i require another file in different path

`file_get_content()` cause alot of erros, because the required file have  `file_get_content()` in it

example : in the original file.php

`file_get_content('1/2/file.txt')` in the protected files doesn't have this path so i will have

**failed to open stream: No such file or directory in.....**

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Comment: @rndus2r failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: the problem is there's no file directory because of the first problem

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question, maybe split it too (it is better to issue one question for problem you have to confront to). Your request miss two fundamental parts: what is the error you get, and what is the expected behaviour. For example, the second part of your question can be easily solved just by creating manually the file (or tuning the path). is this a praticable fix (or you have to intercept the missing file and issuing a  message via email / file a log entry or similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `header()` problem because of `require` ofcourse the login.php have if statement

```
if ($_SESSION["logged"] == false)
```

so your `header()` doesn't work actually the required file working **automatically**!

you can solve it easily with
add to your protected files

```
<?php
    session_start();
if ($_SESSION["loggedIn"] == false) {
header('location: file.php');

?>
```

it will work better and will solve the `file_get_content()` problem

it took 10min to know what do you mean from editing history :D

Comment: np why you add require() ?? if you want just session

Comment: because there's another variabls and things i want i just added a simple example code but no problem i will make third file